Is there a way to time the sale of a property in Russia to minimize the risk of a sudden collapse of the Russian rouble right after the deal?
My language exchange partner lives in Russia and plans to sell his apartment and use the money to buy a new one. For some technical and legal reasons specific to his case, the two transactions have to be at least about a week apart. This means he will need to keep a large sum of money, around US$150,000, in Russian roubles in a bank for at least about a week.
I've warned him that Russian rouble is a volatile currency and has experienced sudden collapses in the past, but he says he has no choice. If the rouble were to suddenly collapse by, say, 30% between the two transactions, he would lose that same percentage of the value. Furthermore, a sudden collapse could freeze the real estate market in Russia until the rouble stabilizes — and it could lose even more value by then.
Question: What factors should he monitor to pick the right week for the transactions? News, stock exchange indexes, rouble exchange rates, oil prices? How can he assess the risk of a particular week in advance? How would you choose the best week for the transactions to minimize the risk of a sudden rouble collapse if you had no other choice?
Ideally, I would like an explanation using the next week (21–27 Oct 2024) as an example to illustrate the rouble collapse risk assessment.

Will the agreed prices of the apartments be in rubles? If he has a contract to sell one apartment for 15 million rubles and a contract to buy another for 15 million rubles, why does it matter if the exchange rate changes in between? Or do the contracts specify the price as a USD equivalent, but paid in rubles according to some exchange rate? If so, it is important to specify exactly how and on what date the exchange rate is determined for each transaction.

In other words, what matters is not the period of time that he physically holds rubles, but what amount of exchange rate risk he is exposed to by the terms of the apartment sales contracts. Suitable negotiation of those contracts could hedge the risk.

@nanoman My friend sells his apartment to Person A and then buys an apartment from Person B. The contracts specify the prices in roubles. Both prices have already been agreed on, and the contracts are being prepared. The risk is this: my friend sells his apartment and gets 15 million roubles, then the rouble collapses, prompting Person B to withdraw from the deal, leaving my friend with 15 million roubles. What my friend is looking for is some indicators he could use to choose the exact moment of the first transaction to minimize the risk of the rouble collapsing before the second transaction

I think the key issue is, how does Person B withdraw from the deal? Is this a common occurrence there? If you can't rely on a contract, how you do anything? Are you saying, even though your friend would have the law on his side, his only remedy in that event would be an expensive lawsuit?

I’m voting to close this question because it requires specialized legal assistance from someone familiar with the Russian escrow and contract laws. Talk to a local attorney.

@nanoman The contract is prepared before the deal and is signed on the day of the transaction. That's the common practice in Russia. Before the contract is signed, Person B can withdraw from the deal with minimal consequences (like losing the deposit of about US1,000)

@littleadv Of course, my friend has talked to a local lawyer. My question is specifically about how to choose a good week to do both transactions in order to minimize the risk of a sudden collapse of the rouble between the transactions. Just that. The question is focused on the financial part and sets the legal part aside.

@Mitsuko I think the key word here is "sudden". As we all know attempts to time the market are usually futile.

@littleadv I thought that sudden collapses do not come entirely out of the blue. There must be some warning signs beforehand suggesting a potential risk of a sudden collapse. Stock exchange indexes, actions of the Central Bank, unusual dynamics of the exchange rate, etc... If absolutely everything is normal, then there's no reason for a sudden collapse. So, I am looking for practical advice as to what signs he should watch for

Generally, the signs are there already: the country is at war, facing crippling sanctions that affect the international trade, under a dictatorship with little regard to the rule of law or personal freedoms, and on a brink of economic collapse. Whether the collapse happens next week or next year - anyone's guess.

Seems to me that if a lot of really smart and informed people didn't see the financial crisis of 2008 coming, it's pretty hard to predict these sort of financial events especially deciding which week of the year it will happen. Even the people who thought the financial crisis of 2008 was imminent, couldn't predict the exact week.

Well, theoretically they can exchange rubles for dollars, and keep money in dollars for this week. Nowadays it may be not so easy, because it would need to be physical dollars (i.e. cash, not some numbers on a bank account), getting $150k in cash from a random bank will most probably be very difficult, but not impossible (or contact several banks, or maybe they can exchange only a half of the sum to diversify). Obviously this will incur some losses due to spread, and there are standard risks of handling cash, so that's up to them to calculate if the risks of keeping rubles are worth it.

@Petr That introduces specific risk that the Ruble strengthens over the period in question. Whether that risk is more a concern than the risk of economic collapse + 'Person B' backs out of their legal agreement, I cannot say.

I'm voting to close because it is asking for very subjective opinions on how to predict economic collapse; more actionable advice as mentioned may relate to legally structuring the agreement through use of escrow account etc. that would prevent 'Person B' from backing out of the deal. That also would be off-topic for this site, and the asker has indicated they are not looking for such advice anyway.
